# How to process Gamma correction if having RGB data

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have RGB data and Gamma correction ration

Can I use the following to calculate

```
R = pow(R, 1/Gamma)
G = pow(G, 1/Gamma)
B = pow(B, 1/Gamma)
```

or Gamma correction only applies to intensity.(brightness)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work correctly. For most RGB color encodings, gamma is applied per-channel.

Just be careful, R, G, and B are expected to be on a range [0,1] before applying the inverse gamma function.

Answer (score 0):

I think it shall be pow(R, gamma) and not 1/gamma and the same goes for the rest of the channels 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction